# Need explaination on Software Design questions checklist asked by UML modeling tool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, invariants, argouml

I am trying to digest a large Java Application by modeling it in UML using ArgoUML. In the properties section of the UML diagramming tool there is a helpful checklist that I am assuming is used to help design good software. Most of the checklist items make sense except for 3.

```
1). Could you write an invariant for this class? 
2). Do all constructors establish the class invariant? 
3). Do all operations maintain the class invariant?
```

What is meant by these questions? I am new to object oriented design so an explanation would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you Googled the term, "invariant"? Understanding of this appears to be the key to your question.

Comment: look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant

Comment: I can't understand why I keep getting down votes on this. I don't get invariants and what these questions are really asking. An explanation would help. I have googled it and have found that its something in your application that does not change and can be used as the control in writing your tests. Still, I don't know what these questions are really asking.. Constructors establish the class invariant? (what does this have to do with an unchanging condition?)  Maintain the class invariant?? (What??) I need an example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an easy example: When you model a triangle, you want to make sure that the sum of the angles always adds up to 180 degrees.

```
class Triangle {
    number angle1, angle2, angle3;
}
```

This is the invariant (a condition that is supposed to be always true):

```
degrees (angle1 + angle2 + angle3) = degrees 180
```

Now the second question makes sense: since a constructor must make sure not to construct an object where the invariant doesn't hold.

The third question, then, asks if there are operations that could invalidate the invariant. For example:

```
    void setAngle1(number whatever) { angle1 = whatever; }
```

And here it turns out that the design above is not good.
Why? Becasue there are redundant information.
A better design would be this:

```
class Triangle {
    number angle1, angle2;   // two angles
    number side;             // and the connecting line
}
```

We can always compute angle3 from angle1 and angle2. And we just need to enforce the simpler invariant that `angle1 + angle2 < 180°` and `side > 0`